# Force UITableView to Scroll to Tops of Cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there a way to make UITableViews scroll cell to cell? That is, the top of the Table View is always the top of a UITableViewCell.

I tried the pageation flag, but that seems to scroll whole "pages." I just want cell to cell scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

`UTTableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can use `scrollViewDidScroll` method to rearrange your TableView scroll position after scroll.

You can use `tableView.contentOffset` to get where is your current scroll position. And by dividing it to a meaningful number you can get which cell is on top.

```
int cellIndex = tableView.contentOffset / cellHegiht;
```

Or you can get currently visible cell on center (top, bottom) like this:

```
NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [indexPathsForVisibleRows objectAtIndex:(indexPathsForVisibleRows.count / 2)]; //this gets center cell
```

After calculating which cell should be clicked by its edge on top (or bottom) you can correct the drift from cell edge by calling:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to activate snapping. You can activate either when the scrolling animation completed or while the animation still continues. This will generate different user interaction and can't say one is better then another.

But just implementing following method and nothing else looks like going to be my favorite:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    int cellHeight = 41;
    *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(targetContentOffset->x,
                                       targetContentOffset->y - (((int)targetContentOffset->y) % cellHeight));
}
```

This method gets called when user touches up on `TableView` to notify application. `targetContentOffset` is an `inout` variable so you can actually set final scroll position while animation is continuing. Using right `cellHeight`, your `TableView` will always snap to cells.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use the `inout` variable. Very nice feature!

Comment: With your math - you cant ever scroll to the last row in the table... not a problem to remedy though. - definitely the best solve for this.

Comment: @scottbates22 actually your point of view is just irrelevant for this occasion since the snapping point is the top of the table view and last cell being at the very top of table view is not a common practice. Cell height must be equal or bigger than the table view's height for your math. Even in that situation, user should still be able to scroll to last cell because any target scroll position above (cellNumber - 1) * cellHeight should snap the last cell.

Answer (score 3):

If you have sections, I found this the most reliable approach:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (decelerate == NO) {
        [self autoAdjustScrollToTop];
    }
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self autoAdjustScrollToTop];
} 
- (void)autoAdjustScrollToTop {
    // compare the top two visible rows to the current content offset
    // and auto scroll so that the best row is snapped to top
    NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    NSIndexPath *firstPath = visibleRows[0];
    NSIndexPath *secondPath = visibleRows[1];
    CGRect firstRowRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:firstPath];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(firstRowRect.origin.y > self.tableView.contentOffset.y ? firstPath : secondPath) atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although totally correct, I didn't find the answer by @randle very helpful. I read the developers documentation, and I was even more confused. How ever I finally discovered how simple the answer was, but sometimes we need a little but more help than "call this method". See under the comment // scroll to row! here:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    if (textField == self.firstInput) {
        [self.secondInput becomeFirstResponder];

        // scroll to row!
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: // use the method
             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1     // get 2nd row (nth row...)
                                inSection:0]    // in 1st section (...)
                         // set position: you can use bottom, middle or top.
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom  
                                 animated:YES]; // YES or NO.

    } else if (textField == self.secondInput) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now, this is for a static cell tableView. I know the amount of rows, I know which row I am going to. This could be expanded out to better code, and accessing variables programmatically, but it show HOW this code works in practice at a low level.

I hope this adds a layer of usefulness to anyone else searching the forum.

I did a complete write up of the method here: http://iosanswers.blogspot.com/2012/02/table-view-forms-scroll-to-selected.html

Answer (score 1):

This approach handles a table view with varying row heights. It assumes the table view has a single section.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    // Find the row where the animation will currently end.
    NSInteger targetRow = [[self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:*targetContentOffset] row];

    // Tell the animation to end at the top of that row.
    *targetContentOffset = [self offsetForTopOfRow:targetRow];
}
```

The offset is calculated by this helper method, which sums the heights of all rows above the target row.

```
- (CGPoint)offsetForTopOfRow:(NSInteger)row {

    CGPoint offset = CGPointZero;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        CGFloat height = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        offset.y += height;
    }

    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` and pass it the right index path for the cell you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works well if you have sections and rows with static heights.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    // Adjust target offset so that cells are snapped to top
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44
    let headerHeight: CGFloat = 30
    let section = (indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.section ?? 0) + 1
    targetContentOffset.memory.y -= (targetContentOffset.memory.y % cellHeight) - (CGFloat(sectionIndex) * headerHeight)
}
```