# how set table view to show a single row only in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, tableview

In my application I have table view cells with height of table view. When user scrolls it some times stops in between two cells, that is by showing half a cell,cell separator and half of other cell.

Is there any way by which I can scroll the table, after user rotation to a single cell?
[image: Sample Screen shot]

What we want is the table view should scroll to a single row automatically after user scroll.

Comment: Could you please explain it further more precisely.

Comment: Take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797693/force-uitableview-to-scroll-to-tops-of-cells

Comment: thanks Hussain,i know i can rotate using the method  'scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:' but i did know where to call it.Is there any method which is called after table scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` for scrolling to top cell. And as a `UITableView` is also `UIScrollView` so you can do it in UIScrollview's delegate method.

```
scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
```

Comment: thanks Abid, solved by implementing method - **'(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset'**